# Error starting Micronaut server: Bean definition [hibernate.SessionFactory] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean [ValidatorFactoryConfigurer]

Tags: hibernate, micronaut, sessionfactory, micronaut-data

I got the following error when I upgraded my project to Micronaut 4.3.1:

```
ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Bean definition [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.configuration.hibernate.jpa.conf.sessionfactory.configure.internal.ValidatorFactoryConfigurer]

Message: Multiple possible bean candidates found: [DefaultConstraintValidatorFactory, DefaultInternalConstraintValidatorFactory]
Path Taken: SessionFactoryPerDataSourceFactory.buildHibernateSessionFactoryBuilder(SessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder) --> new SessionFactoryPerDataSourceFactory(Environment environment,[List configures],StandardServiceRegistryBuilderCreator serviceRegistryBuilderSupplier,List standardServiceRegistryBuilderConfigurers,JpaConfiguration jpaConfiguration,ApplicationContext applicationContext,Integrator integrator) --> new ValidatorFactoryConfigurer([ValidatorFactory validatorFactory])
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Bean definition [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.configuration.hibernate.jpa.conf.sessionfactory.configure.internal.ValidatorFactoryConfigurer]

It seems like a Hibernate Configuration problem. Has anyone encountered that?

I am using Micronaut Data Hibernate JPA and I was expecting the application to run normally as it used to with version 4.2.X.
```

Comment: can you add your `build.gradle` or `pom.xml` to the question. It's hard to tell whats causing the issue without having an idea of your build setup (what dependencies are you using).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.